# jQuery this() doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, this

I have this simple form & validation and everything works perfectly fine excepting 'this' points to, well, I have no idea what:

```
$('#contact').validator().submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: this.action,
          data: { 
            mail: jQuery('input[name="mail"]').val(), 
            message: jQuery('textarea[name="message"]').val(),
          success: function(){
            $(this).hide();
          }
        }); 
    });
```

I want this code to hide #contact on success but this never happens.

I tried to `alert(this)`, but I'm getting `[object Object]`, the same happened when I did `console.log( $(this) )` (there's only Object with + next to it and when I click + I see all sorts of data excepting class / id of this element :( ). Any ideas? Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You lose the context. In `submit` function `#contact` element is the context. In ajax callback ajax settings is the context.

From jQuery Documentation:

> The this reference within all callbacks is the object in the context
>   option passed to $.ajax in the settings; if context is not specified,
>   this is a reference to the Ajax settings themselves.

```
$('#contact').validator().submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var self = this;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: this.action,
    data: {
      mail: jQuery('input[name="mail"]').val(),
      message: jQuery('textarea[name="message"]').val(),
      success: function () {
        $(self).hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This is part of the problem, when I declare `something = $('#contact')` and then use `something` on success it works. BUT when I try to use `this` instead of `$('#contact')` then it changes nothing. Any ideas why?

Comment: looks like I had to add `$` before variable's name to make it work. Any ideas why? I'm just curious if you have any theories.

Comment: Speransky Danil, you misunderstood me, as I said I had to add `$` to variable name (so I declared the variable before). The big question is, why `var x` holds the new ajax contex while `var $x` caches the old context I want :)

Answer (score 1):

`this` within the context of `success` method doesn't refer to the clicked element, you should cache the element:

```
$('#contact').validator().submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this); // cache the object
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: this.action,
          data: { 
            mail: jQuery('input[name="mail"]').val(), 
            message: jQuery('textarea[name="message"]').val()
          }, // missing }
          success: function(){
            $this.hide();
          }
        }); 
});
```

Comment: I was aware of the fact that this was within the context of success method, but looks like it works only when I do `var $something = $(this)` and does not work with `var something = $(this)`, any idea why is it like this? Is there any major difference between `var x` and `var $x`? Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @Wordpressor You are welcome, there is no difference between those variables. `$` is only a convention which is used for referring to jQuery objects.

Comment: Then it's really strange that it works with `$` and doesn't without :)